# Changing css value of <th> in DataTable with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I am using dataTables and I want to change font color of th to red when specific requirements are met, but it doesn't work.
This th displays sum of one column. Data is inserted with ajax dynamically via DataTables api.

If I change the element on which to do the .css("color", "red") it works as long as it is outside the table.

**jquery**

```
desna = $('#skupina').DataTable({
    "paging": false,
    "scrollY": "700px",
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    //stateSave: true,
    bInfo: false,
   "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [ 1 ],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": false
        }],    
    "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
        var api = this.api(), data;

        // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
        var intVal = function ( i ) {
            return typeof i === 'string' ?
                i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 : typeof i === 'number' ? i : 0;
        };

        // Total over all pages
        total = api
            .column( 3 )
            .data()
            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0 );

        // Total over this page
        pageTotal = api
            .column( 3, { page: 'current'} )
            .data()
            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0 );

        // Update footer
        $( api.column( 3 ).footer() ).html(
            pageTotal +' kg'
        );
    }
});
$('#druga').on("change", "#vozilo", function () {
     var g = $('#grupa').val();
    max_kg = parseInt($(this).children(":selected").attr("id"));
    if(max_kg<pageTotal){
        alert("nope");
        $("#foto").css( "color", "red"  );
    };
});
```

**php**

```
function zaglavlje($row, $rbr) {

echo '<thead>';
echo '<tr>
    <th>Adresa</th>
    <th>Grad</th>
    <th>Drzava</th>
    <th><input type="checkbox" id="all'.$rbr.'" align="center"/></th>

</tr>
<tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="10" id="foto" contenteditable="true"></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>';
echo '</thead>';

}
```

Comment: without code, we can't help you...

Comment: Put your code here.

Comment: add running sample code

Comment: Try to add class responsible for color in CSS - that's much more reliable

Comment: What is `#druga` and `#grupa`? Seems to me that `max_kg<pageTotal` never is evaluated to true. Since `#foto` exists there is no other reason for the `css()` not working. Besides that, your HTML as malformed. You have the `<tfoot>` inside the `<thead>` ....

Answer (score 0):

I gave this th a class and it worked when I called .css() on that class.

Comment: Hard to believe that a `css()` work on a existing class but not an existing id. In fact it is quite impossible :)

Answer (score 0):

i think you are looking for

```
    $('#example').dataTable( {
    "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
      $('#example tr:eq(0) th:eq(0)').text("Text update by code");
    }
  } );
```

Same As if you would like to set column using DataTable then Please [click Here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().header())